# How to get datetime value from a custom field correctly?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, netsuite, suitescript

I'm working in serverside in RESTlets.

I’m in the UK, so I have a different timezone to the NS servers. When I put a value into a datetime custom field I specify the timezone like this:

```
var dateTime = new Date();

record.setDateTimeValue(‘fieldid', nlapiDateToString(dateTime, 'datetimetz'), ‘America/Los_Angeles’);
```

dateTime is 2017-02-10T18:24:02.000Z

And then NS displays my value properly

[image]

But I can’t see how to get the value out properly.

I’ve got the value in the results of a search and I tried this:

```
var dateTimeValue = nlapiStringToDate(result.getValue(‘fieldid'), 'datetime');
```

But that returns 2017-02-11T02:24:00.000Z

This value has two problems:

1. The time is wrong.
2. The seconds are zeroed.

I don't mind about the seconds at the moment but how can I make the time be right? Presumably I'm doing something wrong with timezones.

Comment: You appear to be specifying a timezone of 'America/Los_Angeles' (which is UTC-0800) in the first example, but no timezone in the second. Apparently you're in UK which is likely UTC+0000. The time difference between the two is -08:00 so yes, probably  a timezone issue (I have no idea about the seconds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the date using a method from the object nlobjSearchResult, which does not allow you to specify a time zone. In order to get the correct value, unfortunately in this case you need to load the record, then get the value using the time zone API.

For example, in your case, you would first get the record ID from the "result" object:

```
var id = result.getId();
```

Then, you use the load record API to load the record:

```
var record = nlapiLoadRecord(recordType, id);
```

Where "recordType" is the ID of you record type/entity.

Finally, you use the date/time zone API to get the date/time field correctly, in the time zone you need:

```
var nsDateTimeValue = record.getDateTimeValue('fieldId', 'America/Los_​Angeles'); 
//nsDateTimeValue is a string

var jsDateTimeValue = nlapiStringToDate(nsDateTimeValue, 'datetimetz');
//jsDateTimeValue is a JavaScript Date object in the correct timezone with seconds
```

Comment: Thanks. I added more code to your answer to fully solve my problem.

Answer (score -4):

I would just convert it over myself.  If it is +8 hours...

```
dateTimeValue.setHours(dateTimeValue.getHours() + 8);
```